# API mismatch setting up CefGlue

Tags: c#, linux, windows, mono, cefglue

I tried to setup CefGlue for using the Cef webbrowser control in c# with mono.
I tried all the combination between CefGlue and Cef version but I still have a Cef API mismatch.

This is the CefGlue version : https://bitbucket.org/xilium/xilium.cefglue/src/335450e6011dcaeb5afd5fd890fb6f0677d28325/

CefGlue website says "Currently supported version is CEF 3.1650.1503." but this version of Cef doesn't work. I'm using VS 2013, compiling for x86.

*(my goal is to have a webcontrol in a form (using windows forms) on both Linux and Windows systems.)*

Thank you.

Comment: Latest sources are compatible with v3.2171.1949.